# When a short circuit happens in one circuit of a DB, the main ELCB of 10 DBs trip simultaneously

Tags: circuit-breaker

A total of 31 distribution boxes (DBs) are available.

The earth-leakage circuit breakers (ELCBs) of 10 DBs trip simultaneously when a short circuit happens in one circuit of a DB.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please draw a detailed wiring diagram showing the position of the DBs and the ELCBs. You also need to indicate details of how the short occurs.

Comment: Phase wire insulation get damaged and touched with the cable tray body.

Comment: Main supplies multiple devices, so doesn't this make sense.  Reset main and problem goes away?